# Why is my code working fine with python 2.7 but outputting nothing with python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Basically, the problem is to print all numbers from 1 to 1000 wherein the square of the number consists only of even numbers(Eg : 932**2 = 868624, all digits are even digits)
I am sure I got the algorithm, got it working fine with python 2.7, but is failing with python 3.4. Seems pretty strange.
Anyways, here is the code:

```
for x in range(1,1000): #x varies from 1 to 1000
    sq = x*x
    flag = True
    while sq != 0:
        if sq %2 != 0:    #everytime sq is divided by 10, result is even
            flag = False
            break
        sq /= 10
    if flag:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Comment: You don't need the final `x += 1` - this will in fact cause your loop to skip some numbers.

Comment: @AaronD Just to clarify, it would not cause skipping of numbers, but yes its useless line. for loop would always pick up the next number from `range()` changing `x` within the loop would not affect that.

Comment: @AaronD : This won't skip numbers, but is useless, indeed

Comment: @AaronD One is free to modify the iteration variable without affecting the iteration itself (ie `range(1,1000)` will yield the numbers 1..1000 regardless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Shows that the problem is in line 8. Python 3 uses `/` only for float division, use `//` instead.

Source; http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189

```
for x in range(1,1000):
    sq = x*x
    flag = True
    while sq != 0:
        if sq %2 != 0:
            flag = False
            break
        sq //= 10 # <-- here
    if flag:
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Now, the Output should look like this :

```
    2   
    8
    20
    22...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x , The result of `/` is `float` , Example -

```
>>> 868624/10
86862.4
```

Whereas in Python 2.x , when both operands to `/` were integer , it did integer division.

You need to do -

```
sq //= 10
```

---

Also, as suggested in the comments, you do not need `x+=1` line at the end of the for loop , though that would not cause any skipping of numbers, its useless, you can remove that line.

This is because changing the `x` variable inside the for loop would not affect the range, and the for loop would take the next number from range and assign it to `x` for the next iteration.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind commenting on why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

As other answers said: use `//`. But I want to add a note:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Add this line at the start of your file, it will make division the same behaviour in python 2.x and 3.x . It should be useful when you want to write 2.x and 3.x compatible programs.

---

**Before**:

python 2.x

```
>>> 3 / 2
1
>>> 3 // 2
1
```

python 3.x

```
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
>>> 3 // 2
1
```

**After**:

python 2.x  && python 3.x

```
>>> 3 / 2
1.5
>>> 3 // 2
1
```